# offset errors in opamp in DC and AC

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

I want ask about When the offset errors be more serious, when amplifying dc or ac signal in op-amp i search but noting found in this area

Comment: You cannot amplify a DC signal...Gain is defined only for changes in input.

Comment: Look up the supplemental data supplied with many popular op-amps and you will find this subject is covered often. @sarthak. Huh? Both AC and DC signals can be amplified. You must be confusing differential mode with common mode signals.

Comment: I understand that A.C. operation is not affected by them (they just add an offset), and Negative feedback reduces the effect of both, but the question how it effect if input is DC signal?

Comment: @Sparky256 DC signals just give the operating points... Gain is defined for small signal changes only.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "serious" and what your system requirements are.

If you have an AC coupled amplifier, DC offset may not be important at all unless the gain is so high that the offset reduces the required headroom.

If your amplifier is DC coupled but the offset is tolerable in your system, it may not matter at all either.

It's only if the offset is large enough that your system requirements can't be met that it becomes a problem.  And then only if it can't be calibrated out, or otherwise nulled.

Comment: thank you 'john D' i'm still not understand it in DC it more effect more than AC is that right,So why?

Comment: You are talking about the DC offset spec you read on an op-amp's datasheet, correct?  If so, many AC amplifiers are AC coupled, meaning that the don't pass DC from stage to stage.  So a small offset in one stage is removed by the high pass filter and doesn't appear in the next stage.  This does not occur for DC coupled stages and can cause inaccuracy.

Comment: hello 'john D'  i'm talking offset in general what happing if op-amp happen in output signal if input is DC and if input is AC?i undestand that AC amplifiers don't pass DC from stage and small offset remove by high pass filter how that it just DC offset now frequency add? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thermal distortion, as the diffpairs experience transient thermal imbalances, is one source of AC offsets.

Here is thermal distortion at level of 34 microVolts output distortion; Vsensor is 10 milliVolts; the opamp has 10 ohms Rg and 990 ohms Rfeedback.

Note the Thermal Distortion, shown in lower left of screen shot, occurs at LOW FREQUENCIES where the silicon-die has time to propagate the output transistor heating to the differential-pair at input to opamp.

Note this is a GENERIC MODEL of opamp thermal distortion. If you have more information about your particular OpAmp's behavior, or you have die sizes, spacing between output devices and input diffpair, thickness of the silicon, die-attach Rthermal, etc, you can edit the thermal properties.

Also note the thermal noise plot, at lower right. At high frequencies, the ADC input R "S2:R" boosts the total noise.

[image]

Comment: hello 'analogsystemsrf' i don't understand